# how to get bootstrap textbox value in asp.net code behind and send as parameters in store procedure?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, stored-procedures

I have following code on customer.aspx page. Now how can I use textbox and dropdown button's values in codebehind file to send as parameter of the store procedure ? textbox and dropdown must be build from Bootstrap only

```
<div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Smith">
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        <div class="form-group ">
        <select class="form-control col-sm-10">
            <option value="0" selected>Select Gender</option>
             <option value="1">Male </option>
             <option value="2">Female</option>
             <option value="3">Others</option>
         </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Codebehind file:

```
public void Enroll_Customer()
{ 
    String CS =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PortfolioMgmtConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))

{

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[spAddNewCustomer]", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;               

cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
Request.Form("firstname");

cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.Text).Value = ddlCategory.SelectedValue;
con.Open();
cmd.executeNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Web Form, if we want to retrieve a control's data from postback, we want to use a server control as much as possible.

The main reason is it is not easy to maintain a control's state, unless you manipulate `ViewState` manually.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FirstNameLabel" 
                AssociatedControlId="FirstNameTextBox" Text="First Name"/>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstNameTextBox"
                CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Smith" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="GenderDropDownList" 
                    CssClass="form-control">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Select Gender" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Male" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Female" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Others" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public void Enroll_Customer()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["PortfolioMgmtConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddNewCustomer", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstNameTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", GenderDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!,  Thanks Win.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

```
Request.Form("firstname");
```

in your form, the input first name should have

```
name="firstname";
```

but in your form now, it just has id attribute.
It's not belong to bootstrap.